# docker desktop cannot start, an unexpected error ocurred

Tags: docker, dockerfile, desktop

A timeout occured while waiting for a WSL integration agent to become ready.

This can occur when starting after an abrupt termination. To work around the issue, please terminate WSL (wsl --shutdown) and start Docker Desktop again. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-terminal).

Error details:
1 error occurred:
* starting WSL integration service: synchronising agents: starting added distros: 1 error occurred:
* waiting for WSL integration for Ubuntu: waiting for WSL distro integration to become ready in "Ubuntu": timeout

I try wsl --shutdown but this isn´t still func, I restart again and again the pc, ok the first time the instalation boot(restart) itself the computer, i make everythings but dont get as well results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

See the answer from [this post](https://forums.docker.com/t/win10-a-timeout-occured-while-waiting-for-a-wsl-integration/135211/2).

Navigate to `Appdata/Roaming/Docker` folder in your user account
Open the settings file(JSON file) and make sure the below settings are as shown:

```
"integratedWslDistros" : [ ]
"enableIntegrationWithDefaultWslDistro" : false,
```

Save the changes and restart docker desktop